# mysql: RIGHT JOIN query speed issues involving calendar table

Tags: mysql, database-design, join

UPDATE: It seems the problem (as noted as various people) is changing a datetime field into a date field in the query.

Using `DATE( all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date` is too slow, is there a quicker method without either changing actioned_date into a date field or splitting it into a date and time field?

I have 2 tables, one with a load of records that have a status and a datetime field and the other is a calendar table with dates from 2008 to 2015.

What I want to get out is every date in a time period and the number of records that have been "accepted" each day - even if that count is zero - which would look like this:

```
| Date      | number_accepted |
 ----------------------------
 2012-03-01     723
 2012-03-02     723
 2012-03-03     1055
 2012-03-04     1069
 2012-03-05     0
 2012-03-06     615
 2012-03-07     0
 2012-03-08     1072
 2012-03-09     664
 2012-03-10     859
 2012-03-11     0
 2012-03-12     778
 2012-03-13     987
```

I've tried the following, but it is only fast enough on a small sample of data (-1000 rows).  I need something that is works well on at least 600k rows

```
SELECT calendar.datefield AS Date, 
       COUNT( all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status ) AS total_griefs
FROM all_griefs_tbl
RIGHT JOIN calendar 
   ON ( DATE( all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date ) = calendar.datefield )
   AND all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status = 'accepted'
WHERE calendar.datefield < CURDATE( )
GROUP BY calendar.datefield
```

Thanks

EDIT: Execution plan as requested

```
 id select_type     table           type    possible_keys     key               key_len     ref     rows    Extra
 1  SIMPLE          calendar        range   PRIMARY           PRIMARY           3           NULL    1576    Using where; Using index
 1  SIMPLE          all_griefs_tbl  ref     actioned_status   actioned_status   153         const   294975
```

Comment: Please provide the execution plan (the output when you add explain before the select)

Comment: your calendar table with every date.  Are you always going for every day since 2008 to whatever the current date is?  You might just be better with a summary table with the counts per day instead of recomputing every time.

Comment: The idea was to get the data for a highstocks chart - http://www.highcharts.com/ so from 2008 to current would be ideal.  I can get counts per day as long as there is at least 1...I guess that would be the fall back if I can't get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts...

First, although you state that you want days without any values returned in the db query, I would actually do this check on the result set wherever that is being handled. Whenever you do a join, you make your queries much more complicated and require more memory to handle them. In this case, I wouldn't regard you use of the calendar table as a particular good use of a relational database.

EDIT: To clarify, how is the query being called? i.e. is there some program (that you're developing) accessing the database, running the query and presenting the results? If so, I'd suggest getting this program to process the results before presentation.

Second, if you're committed to the 'join', you really should have an index on `all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date` since this is the column on which you're doing the join. Alternatively, you could specify a foreign key on `calendar.datefield`.

Third, do you need to use the function `DATE(all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date)`? Isn't this already a date? (Not sure of your data types, but if this and `calendar.datefield` are not the same data type, this looks like bad database design.)

EDIT: In light of what you say, you may want to split `all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date` into two columns a date column `all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date` and a timestamp column `all_griefs_tbl.actioned_time`. At the moment, you're running this `DATE()` function on every row in `all_griefs_tbl` in order to do the join - this will very quickly make the query sluggish. This would also allow you to add an index on both *date* and *time* columns, which would also improve the performance of the join (Given your current db design, I'm not surprised the index on `actioned_date` didn't help - I'd rather expect that, because of the `DATE()` function, if you rerun `EXPLAIN` with an index on the `actioned_date` column as it currently stands, it wouldn't show it using this index on `all_griefs_tbl`.)

Fourth, you may want to consider what types of information are stored in `all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status`. Could this be replaced by a boolean? This would be more efficient in both storing and processing the data. (Although again, this depends on your database design.)

EDIT: You could consider changing `all_griefs_tbl.action_status` to a smaller datatype - I expect it's currently a varchar, but you could easily change this to a single (or small) char datatype, or even to a number of booleans. However, I don't expect this to be the main performance overhead and is really a more involved database design decision depending on the needs of your project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using a calendar table so I get all the dates in a time period, so as not to have any missing.  If there is a better way I would love to hear it.  I'm not committed to the join, I just don't know another way to do it.  I did have an index on  all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date but it didn't seem to make too much of a difference.  calendar.datefield is date field, all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date is a datetime field.  That's the only difference.  There are a few different statuses that all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status could be: accepted, queued, locked

Comment: I'm trying to achieve what is done here: http://www.richnetapps.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/ the difference being I'm counting the number of rows in a time frame instead of summing up values.

Comment: Splitting datetime into date and time with proper indexing should be enough. Other ideas are ok, but not that important from the performance point of view. And I don't think using calendar table is that bad.

Comment: Not sure what I did, but tested removing the DATE() again and it runs 4.77 secs, which is fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest splitting your `actioned_date` from datetime into 2 separate date and time columns, lets say `actioned_date` and `actioned_time` so you could change your first join condition from

```
ON ( DATE( all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date ) = calendar.datefield )
```

to

```
ON ( all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date = calendar.datefield )
```

and adding an index

```
ALTER TABLE all_griefs_tbl ADD INDEX g_status_date( actioned_status, actioned_date, actioned_time );
```

It would probably make your query instant for a table with 600k rows.

Comment: That is one solution I think will work, but what I want to know is if there is another method instead of DATE() that I can use that would be quicker?  Splitting it into 2 separate columns would be the last resort.

Comment: Splitting would allow using mentioned index also for the group by, that would make a difference of talking about msecs instead of seconds.