# Need to combine timestamp field date with varchar field time

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

Im trying to figure out a way to fix a database schema issue.

In column 1 a y-m-d H:i:s date is stored (timestamp field)

```
col1 = 2009-11-12 00:00:00
```

In  column 2 a time is stored (varchar)

```
col2 = 15:48
```

I'm thinking that storing it in one column would be more efficient than separately, so I'm trying to make column 3 a datetime field

```
col3 = 2009-11-12 15:48:00
```

Unless keeping it original is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely use one field, you can get just the date or time from it later if you need. I believe you can run the following query to update col3 with the correct datetimes.

```
UPDATE tablename
SET col3 = CAST(LEFT(col1, 10) + " " + col2 + ":00", DATETIME)
```

If you don't have anything accessing these old fields (col1 and col2), you should get rid of them for clarity. If you do, it is going to be tricky decided whether or not to maintain two fields for the same data.

Answer (score 1):

[`Addtime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) should do what you need

```
mysql> select addtime('2012-05-05 00:00:00', '11:12');
+-----------------------------------------+
| addtime('2012-05-05 00:00:00', '11:12') |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2012-05-05 11:12:00                     |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the other answers... I wouldn't immediately suggest combining these columns.

Consider how the columns are going to be queried - in my experience, efficient queries are more important than disk space efficiency - as such, if you're want to select rows based on date (ignoring time) and/or time (ignoring date) you would want these in separate columns. Whilst you can get the date from a datetime column, if you have *lots* of rows, doing that on each row before running a query would be really inefficient. (For example... consider this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334483/mysql-right-join-query-speed-issues-involving-calendar-table/10336054#10336054))

Comment: After thinking it through I'm going to keep it separate. I'm preferring the efficient queries, thanks